# Best practice for timetable-like database design

Tags: sql, database-design

I was wondering what is the best practice for timetable-like database design? Take for example businesses in a business directory. They have opening / operating hours; Monday to Sunday followed by opening time and closing time for each day. As such what is the best practice for table that contains such information?

The first thing that comes to my mind is having 7 columns for each day in a table. But that doesn't seem very practical and my insecure side tells me that it'll probably put more load to the database.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Four columns: `business`, `day_of_week`, `opening_time`, `closing_time`

This table contains one row for each day of week, with its opening/closing hours. The business column is a foreign key referencing the main table with the business information in it.

Comment: Hi Dan,

Thank you for your reply. If understood correctly, would the four column design be something like this?

`1 Mon 9.30am 5.30pm
1 Tue 9.30am 5.30pm
1 Wed 9.30am 5.30pm
.
.
2 Mon 10am 6pm`

Comment: More like 1,2,09:30,17:30 1,3,09:30,17:30... (in other words, use numbers and times, not strings) but yes, that's what I am suggesting.